# Math pow alternative in java

Tags: java, binary

I have a need to sum up power of 2 from any digit x to 0.
If x=6,desired sum is 2pow6+2pow5+.....1.
While I can always write a algorithm to wind down to 0 using Math.pow - this function seems notorious performance-wise in a loop.
Would appreciate if someone could help achieving the same using shift binary operators - I hear they are much more efficient than pow.

Comment: "this function seems notorious performance-wise" - have you tested this? What values of `x` can you reasonably expect, and is performance critical? What do you already have?

Comment: It's a sum of the geometric progression,there is a formula to do that

Comment: @thegrinner For the record, a quick micro benchmark shows that `pow(2,10)` is about 160 times slower than `1 << 10`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

2^n + 2^(n-1) + 2^(n-2) + ... + 2 + 1 = (2^(n+1) - 1) = `((1 << (n+1)) - 1)`

Comment: Silly of me.Sometimes technology makes us forget that maths may have a solution too!!!

Comment: Most clever and beautiful answer ever

Answer (score 6):

You don't have to calculate it in a loop, what you are trying to compute is equivalent to

```
Math.pow(2, x+1) - 1
```

Even better, you can calculate it like torquestomp suggested, which will be faster:

```
(1 << (x + 1)) - 1
```

Comment: `Math.pow` takes two parameters. Don't you mean `Math.pow(2, x+1) - 1`?